# Why was this suggested edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

The suggested edit can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/941497

What reasons  caused this to be rejected? The reasons weren't clear, and I was the one that both suggested the edit and made the comment, so it wasn't in reply to the comment.

The way I see it, it a) improves the answer b) answers the question with less extra code c) explains what the code does.

Could someone clarify why this was rejected?

Comment: Don't remove code. Make a comment if it's irrelevant in your opinion. But removing code in my opinion is a no no.

Comment: Why on earth did you make the same edit again while you were still discussion the first rejection here? http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/947858

Comment: I've rolled back that second edit. When an edit is rejected by the OP, *please do not make the same edit again*. And making the same edit again while discussing why the first one was rejected is just rude.

Comment: What's "unessecary" code?

Comment: Usually I don't downvote such questions, but in this case you didn't really ask "why" or at least didn't wait for answer before going and doing the same thing again. I totally disagree with such behaviour, and guess most of the downvoters here feel the same.

Comment: I'm curious to know why you think the behavior described by Martijn Pieters is acceptable.

Comment: The answer is in removed part of Edit..that's why i rejected the edit and please go back and refer the diff revision 1 and 2 of edits: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13236800/revisions , s.replaceChar("ABC123", 3, 5) is the main part of answer.I am not rude,,

Comment: @BloodRed: I was calling the OP rude, because he was editing your post twice while discussing the issue here, not you.

Comment: I thought "calling me Rude"..misunderstood ..Sorry

Comment: What the hell happened? I posted this question and then _logged_ _off_. Changing password now...

Comment: What do you mean "what the hell happened"?

Comment: I posted this question, then logged off and shut off my computer. Someone else logged on and started messing with stuff. I have 2 problems now: A) account security B) I don't know what they did

Comment: Haha, so you didn't brazenly re-edit the question twice. Someone broke into your account and maliciously did it to hurt your reputation. Got it. Personally I'd go after something more helpful to me than attacking someone's StackOverflow reputation in such an obscure and specific fashion.

Comment: They may have just logged onto the computer after me and done it there. *I* *DON'T* *KNOW* what happened, or how they did it.

Comment: @azulflame. You can view your account's network-wide activity on your [network profile](http://stackexchange.com/users/1502089/azulflame?tab=activity). I looked through it and didn't notice anything especially suspicious.

Comment: @azulflame My point is who would care enough, after gaining access to a secure terminal with your account, to specifically go back to StackOverflow and re-enter the same edit information. It's like finding out they've left the bank-vault unlocked and instead of going in to steal money you spread dirt and grime everywhere to frame the cleaning crew. It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MikeB, A) The computer that this was on ran Novell (don't even mention security here) and B) I can think of several people that would do that (If you aren't making enemies, you aren't living your life how you should)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The owner of the post rejected it with:

> I have given with basic codiing end to end of the program so that they can understand easily

The original author of a post can veto any suggested edit made. I guess he disagreed with your  change, feeling that the 'unessecary' (sic) code you removed was there for a purpose.

The other reviewer rejected your edit because your change was too radical; changing code is generally frowned upon, unless you are correcting obvious typos in answer code.

Comment: I didn't know about this feature. How do you access it? Is it with rollback?

Comment: @Ren: You get notified when someone edits your post, which links to the suggested edit. There you can approve or reject it. If voters approve it before you get to it, you'll have to manually roll back.

Comment: the answer is in removed part of Edit..that's why i rejected the edit and please go back and refer the diff revision 1 and 2 of edits:http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13236800/revisions , s.replaceChar("ABC123", 3, 5) is the main part of answer.I am not rude,,